# Размытый текст в салайдере owl-carousel

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, шрифты, owl-carousel

На некоторых разрешениях(возможно нет) в Chrome текст на слайдере размытый текст.
На ноутбуке первый слайдер текст нормальный, другие размытые. Очень хорошо заметна разница с Mozilla. Открываем сайт в двух браузерах и разница ощутима.
Даю ссылку на сайт для сравнения seo-boomerang.by
Так же прикрепляю два скриншота
[image: Нормальный текст]

[image: Расплывчатый]

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема, решилась удалением свойства `webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`, попробуйте удалить на селекторе `.owl-carousel .owl-item`.
Попробуйте еще внутри owl.carousel.min.js `this.$stage.css({transform:"translate3d("+b+"px,0px,0px)"` заменить на `this.$stage.css({transform:"translate3d("+b+"px,0px)"` https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/162

Comment: Не помогло, все равно остался прежним

Comment: Попробуйте еще внутри owl.carousel.min.js `this.$stage.css({transform:"translate3d("+b+"px,0px,0px)"` заменить на `this.$stage.css({transform:"translate3d("+b+"px,0px)"` https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/162

Comment: Вариант хороший, и действительно помог на некоторых слайдерах. Но у меня есть слайдер с настройкой "center: true," и для него карусель просто ломается. Так же в статье рекомендуют избавиться от дробей(не помогло).

Comment: Заметил еще один факт. Размытый текст только на четных слайдах. То есть первый нормально, второй размытый, третий нормально, четвертый размытый итд

Answer (score 0):

В Chrome текст выглядит не размытым после замены в `owl.carousel.min.js`:

```
translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
```

на:

```
translate3d(0px, 0px, 0.001px)
```